# Python fastecdsa/ecdsa signing error, cannot convert integer to bits

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography, cryptocurrency, ecdsa

I am trying to implement ScroogeCoin using the fastecdsa library. I currently run into an error that happens when my create_coins function is called. The error points to the signing function (tx["signature"]) and says that it cannot convert an integer type to a byte.

```
import hashlib
import json
from fastecdsa import keys, curve, ecdsa


class ScroogeCoin(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.private_key, self.public_key = keys.gen_keypair(curve.secp256k1) 
        self.address = hashlib.sha256(json.dumps(self.public_key.x).encode()).hexdigest()
        self.chain = [] 
        self.current_transactions = []

    def create_coins(self, receivers: dict):
        """
        Scrooge adds value to some coins
        :param receivers: {account:amount, account:amount, ...}
        """

        tx = {
            "sender" : self.address, # address,
            # coins that are created do not come from anywhere
            "location": {"block": -1, "tx": -1},
            "receivers" : receivers,
        }

        tx["hash"] = hashlib.sha256(json.dumps(tx).encode()).hexdigest()# hash of tx
        tx["signature"] = ecdsa.sign(self.private_key, tx["hash"])# signed hash of tx

        self.current_transactions.append(tx)
        ...
```

When this function is ran in the main function:

```
    ...
    Scrooge = ScroogeCoin()
    users = [User(Scrooge) for i in range(10)]
    Scrooge.create_coins({users[0].address:10, users[1].address:20, users[3].address:50})
    ...
```

It produces this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Scrooge_coin_assignmnet.py", line 216, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\Scrooge_coin_assignmnet.py", line 197, in main
    Scrooge.create_coins({users[0].address:10, users[1].address:20, users[3].address:50})
  File "D:\Scrooge_coin_assignmnet.py", line 27, in create_coins
    tx["signature"] = ecdsa.sign(self.private_key, tx["hash"])# signed hash of tx
  File "C:\Users\d\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\fastecdsa\ecdsa.py", line 36, in sign
    rfc6979 = RFC6979(msg, d, curve.q, hashfunc, prehashed=prehashed)
  File "C:\Users\d\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\fastecdsa\util.py", line 25, in __init__
    self.msg = msg_bytes(msg)
  File "C:\Users\d\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\fastecdsa\util.py", line 153, in msg_bytes
    raise ValueError('Msg "{}" of type {} cannot be converted to bytes'.format(
ValueError: Msg "21783419755125685845542189331366569080312572314742637241373298325693730090205" of type <class 'int'> cannot be converted to bytes
```

I've tried to play around and change it to a byte by using encode on the tx["hash"] as well things like bytes.fromhex() but it still gives the same error. I wanted to ask others who are more skilled and see if they can see how I am messing up.

Comment: In the `ecdsa.sign()` call the order of the arguments is swapped. There may also be other problems, e.g. regarding default values, double hashing, encoding or signature format, see [fastecdsa docs](https://github.com/AntonKueltz/fastecdsa).

Comment: Looks like that was the fix!